# Attachment issue in android using SMTP mail system

Tags: android, email, smtp, email-attachments

Hi I am trying to 'attach an image from a folder' that is to be sent as attachment but its fails to send the mail.

If I remove the multipart section for attachment the mail goes through. Could anyone please help me with this?

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
     final String username = "abc@gmail.com";
        final String password = "123456";



        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });
            try {
                message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("xyz@outlook.com"));
                message.setSubject("Photo"+ jobNo);
                message.setText("Hello,"
                    + "\n\n New job with job no" + " " + jobNo +" "+ "has arrived from Team"+ " "+ teamNo 
                    + "\n\n\n\n Please check the attached images."
                    + "\n\n\n\n\n Thank You");
                message.setContent(multipart);
                BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
                DataSource source = new FileDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CLC/"+jobNo) ;
                messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
                messageBodyPart.setFileName(jobNo); 
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                BodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart(); 
                messageBodyPart2.setText("Hi"); 

                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2); 


                new SendMailTask().execute(message);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Job Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            super.onStart();

    }


public class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask<Message, Void, Void>
{
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Email.this, "Please wait", "Sending mail", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(javax.mail.Message... messages)
    {
        try
        {
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: are you getting any error messages?

Comment: There is no error.  It finishes the activity thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. (see http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=30251)

Could you try to change the order of the MessageBodyPart and MessageBodyPart2? So, first add the message body and then add the attachment.

Comment: Hi had to rearrange the sequence . Now it works thank you.